# inserting a variable on style tag

Tags: javascript, html

I need to change the color of the text based on the drop down list selection.

```
<select id="room2">
    <option>#0808cf</option>
    <option>#0E9E26</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="txtColor">
   John: <p style="color:#0808cf" > test </p>
```

jquery

```
$('#colors').change(function(){
   $('#txtColor').val($("#colors").val());
   var fontColor =  $('#txtColor').val();

});
```

I dont want the change to be in the css cause the select id will not be constant. I want it to be inserted in the p style tag. And also i need the text to be John: test to be in one line. I tried this but not working. Thank you.

```
<p style="color:"+fontColor+" > test </p>
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kX3EN/

Answer (score 5):

Try - http://jsfiddle.net/kX3EN/7/

```
$('#colors').change(function(){
    $('p').css( 'color', $(this).val() );
});
```

Comment: this is good but is there any way i can do it in the style tag ? style="color:"+fontColor+" >.

Comment: Nope. The JS will set `fontColor` during page load, assign it to `p` style and even if you later update the value of `fontColor` - it won't affect the `<p>` without re-applying the new value.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your "John: test" to be on the same line, you need to:

- Change the `p` (block-level) to something like a `span` (inline) *or*
- Force the `p` to act as inline with css (`display: inline`).

Using jQuery, you need to use the `css()` function to change the style attribute of an element. Like so:

```
$('selector for element you want to change').css('color', $("#your-select-element").val());
```

You'll probably put this in an event handler for your `select`:

```
$("select#colors").change(function() {
    $("span.changemycolor").css('color', $(this).val());
    // 'this', in this case, is your select element
});
```

Comment: is there any way to do it in the style tag like so <p style="color:"+fontColor+" >. I need it to be in this code. Thanks

Comment: Why do you "need it to be in this code"? What you 'need' isn't going to work. The above will set the `style` attribute to be `color: X`, where *X* is the value of your `select`. From what I can gather from your question, this is what you want to happen.

Comment: Cause im making a chat and append each <p style="color:#61B06E float:left">. If I do it with your code all the <p> tags will be changed everytime the user selects a different color. I want the color change to be unique to each <p>

Comment: Then give it a class or an ID and change the `$("span.changemycolor")` selector to select based on that class or ID. (By the way, it definitely seems like you want an inline element like a `span` instead of a `p`.)

Comment: this doesnt work '<p id='+fontColor+'>' i tried <p id="currentChat"> but this works the same as the jquery you gave, all <p> are having their color changed each time

Comment: `<p=currentChat>` isn't even valid HTML. I think it would help if you looked up the ideas of [class selectors and ID selectors in CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp). These same selectors can be used with jQuery to select elements on which to perform different actions (like changing the `style` attribute).

Answer (score 0):

got it working by placing the  tag after my html code filter. So everytime I append a message  will be stored as variable and read as JS when the var is sent to the websocket send method. Thank you